# Find a string between 2 other strings in document

Tags: html, awk, sed, grep, between

I have found a ton of solutions do do what I want with only one exception.

I need to search a .html document and pull a string.

The line containing the string will look like this (1 line, no newlines)

```
<script type="text/javascript">g_initHeader(0);LiveSearch.attach(ge('oh2345v5ks'));var _ = g_items;_[60]={icon:'INV_Chest_Leather_09',name_enus:'Layered Tunic'};_[6076]={icon:'INV_Pants_11',name_enus:'Tapered Pants'};_[3070]={icon:'INV_Misc_Cape_01',name_enus:'Ensign Cloak'};</script>
```

The text I need to get is

> INV_CHEST_LEATHER_09

When I use awk, grep, and sed, I extract the data between icon:' and ',name_

The problem is, all three of these scripts scan the entire line and use the last occurring ',name_ thus I end up with

> INV_Chest_Leather_09',name_enus:'Layered
>   Tunic'};_[6076]={icon:'INV_Pants_11',name_enus:'Tapered
>   Pants'};_[3070]={icon:'INV_Misc_Cape_01

Here's the last one I tried

> grep -Po -m 1 "(?<=]={icon:').*(?=',name_)"

I've tried awk and sed too, and I don't really have a preference of which one to use.

So basically, I need to search the entire html file, find the first occurrence of icon:', extract the text right after it until the first occurrence after icon:' of ',name_.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/icon:\047([^\047]+)/,a){print a[1]}' file
INV_Chest_Leather_09
```

Comment: good one.. `match($0,/icon:\047([^\047]+)\047,name_/,a)` will do if both sides of required string has to be included... and `{print a[1]; exit}` if only the first match in entire file is needed

Answer (score 0):

The .* in your regular expression is a greedy matcher, so the pattern will match till the end of the string and then backtrack to match the ,name_ portion. You could try replacing the .* with something like [^,]* (i.e. match anything *except* comma):

```
grep -Po -m 1 "(?<=]={icon:')[^,]*(?=',name_)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

This works, however it seems to omit the -m 1 for grep.

I am now getting 3 results. I can add | head -1 to it but I'd prefer to have one command handle this

Comment: That suggests it's matching from more than one file. What's the full command - how are you specifying the input to the grep command?

Comment: I'm using cat index.html | grep. And I'm only using one input file. I believe this is because all 3 of those outputs are on the same line as the one I need.

Comment: You could try adding .* to the end of the pattern; this would extend the matching portion of the string to the end of the line, so reduce the 3 matches on the line to just one.

Answer (score 0):

Simple ***perl*** approach:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /\bicon:\047([^\047]+)/' file
```

The output:

```
INV_Chest_Leather_09
```